# How to compress Ti.utils.base64encode and decompress using .Net method?

Tags: android, asp.net, compression, titanium, base64

Does anyone know how to compress Ti.Utils.base64encode??
for example i have this code :

```
uploadFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(pathFile, listing[_fileCtr].toString());
uploadFileName = listing[_fileCtr].toString();
encodedFile = Ti.Utils.base64encode(uploadFile.read()).toString();
//Send Image to .NET web service
```

And this is the method in my web services for decompressing image from titanium (if i can compress my image before):

```
static byte[] Decompress(byte[] input)
 {
  using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream(input))
  {
   using (GZipStream zip = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Decompress))
   {
    List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
    int b = zip.ReadByte();
    while (b != -1)
    {
     bytes.Add((byte)b);
     b = zip.ReadByte();

    }
    return bytes.ToArray();
   }
  }
```

Until now, i can't find some method for compressing my byte array so i can decompress them using my .NET method..
If u guys have any information about my problem, please tell me..

Many thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In .Net you can use [`System.Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to converts the specified string, which encodes binary data as base-64 digits, to an equivalent 8-bit unsigned integer array.

```
System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedString);
```

Comment: Hi Sameer, thanks for your answer.. all i need is compress my byte array in titanium application and then transfer it through web service.. do you know how to compress byte array in titanium application?

Comment: No, But i think you are uploading image to server this link might solve your issue [Upload images to a server](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/8471/upload-images-to-a-server).